# can we query on deactivate user on customer portal in login time

Tags: userrecordaccess

I have a issue related to deactivate user

I have a field deactivate reason in user object

Deactivate User should be redirect on login in portal according to deactivate reason(new field on user) field

1.If deactivate reason is 'FCRA Renew' than user should be redirect on new screen.

2.if deactivate reason is Standard than standard Deactivated message “You access is disabled. Contact your site administrator”
should be display.

But when I am query on deactivate user than it is not return the deactivate reason value.

I have login button on customer portal and its return the site.login method.

**Can we query on deactivate user on login time.**

Answer (score 0):

from your post, I guess you were able to query the user record but not the reason field. Does the reason field have appropriate filed level permissions?

Comment: I have a proper permission on reason field in profile.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: below is class code

Answer (score 0):

/*Component*/

td {
    //  Symbol * to target only IE7 and lower version of IE.
     *height:20px;
     *vertical-align:top;
     *padding:2px;
     *padding-bottom:2px;
     *padding-top:0px;
    }

  

 

    
      
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
           {!$Label.site.forgot_your_password_q}
          
          {!$Label.site.new_user_q}

global class SiteLoginController {
    global String username {get; set;}
    global String password {get; set;}

```
global PageReference login() {  
    List<User> lstUser = [Select IsActive, Deactivation_Reason__c from User Where Username=:username  limit 1];
    if(lstUser.size() > 0 ){
       User oUser = lstUser.get(0);
       if(oUser.IsActive == false && oUser.Deactivation_Reason__c.tolowercase().contains('fcra') ){   
         return Site.login(username, password, '/main/deactivateuser');
       }
       else{
         return Site.login(username, password, '/home/home.jsp');
       }
    }
    return Site.login(username, password, '/home/home.jsp');
}

global SiteLoginController () {}
```

}